# A great wife — but not very logical

Tags: situation

There was this husband and wife. They were married this day. On this day, the wife shot the husband, held him under water and then hung him up.

Then they went out on a honeymoon. Wonderful relationship. But how is this logical? Explain.

Comment: Maybe he was lucky and didn't have to spend eternity with her.

Comment: Maybe he was unlucky and she followed him into the afterlife to have the honeymoon.

Comment: This is an old puzzle... perhaps too old for a new generation to relate to.  See also: http://www.gocomics.com/pearlsbeforeswine/2015/02/22

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The wife:

> Took a photograph(shot) of her husband.
>  Held the photographic film under water and then hung it to dry.

NOTE:

> He was in the photograph, so you could use **him** as in, "held **him** under water, and hung **him** up". It's just a tricky way to confuse someone.

Comment: held 'him' under water and then hung 'him' up.
Are we missing the pronoun or are we good to neglect to conclude?

Comment: @Keys Because in the photograph there was his image, so you could use him and say "held **him** under water and hung **him** up". Its just a tricky way to confuse someone.

Comment: Thought that way to, was just curious :)

Comment: I think this is the answer, but I personally think it would be much better to have separated the sentences: "On the day she married her husband, she shot him. She then held him under water and hung him up". or else "...she shot him. She held him under water. She hung him up" -- I think that when you have `him` multiple times in a sentence like this (no clear distinction), it _must_ refer to the same thing. In separate sentences, there _can be_ sufficient distinction.

Comment: I've ruined more digital cameras basting them with photographic developing liquid than I care to count. I thought it would fix the "red eye effect."

Comment: This is definitely the canonical answer to this question (it's not a particularly uncommon one), however I think OP may have just been held back by language barriers.

Comment: @wrangler Add that into your answer.

Answer (score 34):

They were married this day. On this day, the wife shot the husband, held him under water and then hung him up.

> The husband suffers from allergies or panic attacks, so she shot him with an epinephrine pen (epi pen) because of the stressful day.  The wife is a born-again Christian and baptized her husband in the faith, as a sacrament of the marriage.  But they're also BDSM practitioners who like to get their freak on so she trussed him up to get the honeymoon started. So, they sound like some friends of mine.

Then they went out on a honeymoon. Wonderful relationship. But how is this logical? Explain.

Comment: You explained what happened, but you didn't say how it was logical :)

Comment: You mean that this sounds less logical than the accepted answer? :P

Comment: A Christian bondage queen. Yeah, that seems plausible... :-)

Comment: +1 purely because this is the first puzzle I've ever solved on here and I solved it in two seconds with the massively obvious answer, but love how you've come up with an answer that also fits :)

Answer (score 11):

This makes perfect sense if...

> the wife was a photographer who preferred using film and making her own prints. She took a picture of her husband, developed the film (which requires the use of various liquid baths which could easily be mistaken for water by someone whose nose was non-functional :-), then made a print, which again requires the use of various liquid chemical baths, and so forth. After developing the print she hung it up to dry.

Or, of course...

> the wife could be a homicidal maniac with necrophiliac tendencies, in which case going on honeymoon with her (now deceased) husband could, y'know, be her thing.

Lovely girl, though... :-)

Comment: 2nd one seems more plausible doesn't it :P

Comment: @avz2611 - sounds like one of my ex-girlfriends. Run away! Run away!!!!

Comment: a + for number two, the Lewis Carroll method of logic puzzles ;)

Comment: The developing process *does* include rincing. For prints I would leave in a vertical circulating water bath for an extended time, and can see the picture through the clear glass.

Answer (score 4):

> They were married this day(year is not written)and the wife shot him this day(again year not mentioned).So possibly years are different and events took in chronological orders. Honeymoon event occured before she shot him.

Comment: Ummmm...."wonderful relationship"?

Comment: The use of "then" would be incorrect with your proposed chronology.

Comment: Yes, "then" is used in stores to show the passage of time, and order of events. Still, this is a clever interpretation.

Answer (score 4):

> Just after the two magicians got married, they created a new trick to commemorate the occasion.

Comment: I was wondering if someone would do this one.

Answer (score 3):

My first thought for this was:

> 1) she took a photo of him,
>  2) she went swimming with him and hugged him,
>  and then 3) helped him set up a hammock.
>  All things one would do on a honeymoon!

Although I do like the other answers a bit more :)

Answer (score 2):

- **solution 1**

> On this day,the wife shot him, held him under water and then hung him up.

Possible explanation

> "He" wasn't her husband but another person.

So the husband and his wife are

> both professional killers

They both love

> killing

so

> maybe he promised to marry her only if she would prove that she was a real killer and kill a person after the marriage.

and

> Then they went out on a honeymoon. Wonderful relationship.

makes sense now.

> "Oh my dear, lets go now and be together forever. I trust you with my life since you proved to be a real professional killer."

PS: Maybe I added a [lateral-thinking](/questions/tagged/lateral-thinking) tag to the question in my mind...

- **solution 2**

> They were married this day.

Maybe...

> ...the wife (let's call her Alice1) married a woman (Alice2)

so

> On this day,the wife shot him,held him under water and then hung him up.

"him" referring to

> Alice(1 or 2)'s ex-boyfriend (Bob1 or Bob2, depending on whose boyfriend it was)

So we have 4 possibilities:

- > Alice1 killed Bob1 because he cheated on her.
- > Alice2 killed Bob2 because he cheated on her.
- > Alice1 killed Bob2 because she didn't want Alice2 to fall in love with Bob2 again.
- > Alice2 killed Bob1 because she didn't want Alice1 to fall in love with Bob1 again.

Comment: Especially since the wife didn't even have to be married to a man.

Comment: @Inazuma Edited the answer and added another solution.

Comment: @Inazuma It says 'he' so yes, she did.

Answer (score 0):

> The wife was a photographer.  She shot his picture; held the print under water (developer solution) and hung the print to dry.

Answer (score -2):

> Water doesn't develop film as suggested in some answers. She took his picture, baptized him, delayed him, then went on the honeymoon.

Comment: Something to back up what you said?

Comment: Water can definitely be used as a cheap alternative to a stop bath (ie: to rinse off the developer).

Answer (score -3):

> He Took a photograph (shot) of her husband. Held the photographic film under water and then hanged it to dry.

Comment: The answer text should be marked as a spoiler (you can do that from the Answer editor). Also, proper grammar is important.